# Firebase signInWithRedirect() not preserving Vue route params

Tags: firebase, vue.js

I have a Pricing page which has a pricing table and does the following to redirect to a Sign Up page with a route param which determines which price (product) the user picked:

```
methods: {
    subscribe(price) {
      this.loading = true;
      if (!this.loggedIn) {
        this.$router.push({ name: "Sign Up", params: { price: price } });
      }
    },
  },
```

In the Sign Up component, it will console log the correct price from the route param in `mounted` , but after the signIn with google happens and it redirects to the Checkout component, the route param `price` is lost:

```
mounted: function () {
    const googleAuth = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    if (!this.loggedIn) {
      firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(googleAuth);
      firebase
        .auth()
        .getRedirectResult()
        .then((result) => {
          this.$router.push({ name: "Checkout", params: { price: this.$route.params.price } });
          console.log(result);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        if (user) {
          this.loggedIn = true;
        } else {
          // Show sign in screen with button above.
        }
      });
    }
  },
```

Comment: Are you using custom domain with your firebase project?

Comment: No @RussDeneychuk

Comment: I see, your issue had reminded me of this page in docs I saw: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/redirect-best-practices Hopefull it's helpful to some extend.